SpringAI calling Azure OpenAI - 401 Access denied due to invalid subscription key or wrong API endpoint
I'm using SpringAI to call microsoft Azure OpenAI.  I've gone through the process of creating an Azure resource for OpenAI and a deployment.  I've retrieved what I believe are the relevant key and API endpoint from this screen:

These are set correctly in my application.yml file:
spring:
  ai:
    azure:
      openai:
        api-key: 56*****************************1  
        endpoint: https://**************.openai.azure.com/
        chat.options.deployment-name: **************

When I run, I get this message back from Azure:  'Status code 401, "{"error":{"code":"401","message":"Access denied due to invalid subscription key or wrong API endpoint. Make sure to provide a valid key for an active subscription and use a correct regional API endpoint for your resource."}}"'
My question:  Where do I get valid values for subscription key and regional API endpoint?  It would appear that "KEY 1" and "KEY 2" are not the correct values for "subscription" key, and that the listed endpoint is not a valid "regional" endpoint - but where do these values come from?

Solved.  In my case, I was using Environment variables to override the values in application.yml(Spring boot prioritizes environment variables over application.yml or properties).
I did change these environment variables, but VSCode did not pick them up even after restarting - which threw me off. I believe the root problem was that I had two copies of VSCode running, so when I restarted one it simply reused the same environment as the other.  Closing both and restarting fixed the issue.
In the end it had nothing to do with Azure, endpoints, or keys; I had the correct values the whole time.  But there sure are a lot of people encountering this error...
